# Solving Sudoku via Production Rules

Tags: logic, rules, drools, rule-engine, sudoku

I'm trying to solve any Sudoku puzzle using production rules, with Drools as my inference engine. One of the examples packed with Drools is precisely a Sudoku solver, here are the relevant rules:

http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-examples/drools-examples-drl/src/main/rules/org/drools/examples/sudoku/sudokuSolver.drl

... But it doesn't work right. All of the time, one or more cells in the grid end up empty and the program reports the puzzle as "unsolved".

Has anybody built a working inference rule-based solver for Sudoku? it doesn't matter the language or engine used, I would like to see the set of rules so that I can adapt  them for Drools

Comment: The example used to work. Something in the Drools 5.1 release has broken it. Feels like it relies too much on the order that the rules are expected to fire.

Not sure if I would follow the example too strictly if I was making my own. It has salience set in almost every rule and that is a bad practice.

If you manage to make a better Sudoku solver please consider publishing it as a Drools example. I can replace the current example with your version.

Comment: I made an issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2867

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a sudoku solver written in CLIPS here: https://sourceforge.net/p/clipsrules/code/HEAD/tree/branches/63x/examples/sudoku/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use trunk (master on github now), as that's unstable. Use the latest release from the download page. Apparently this example's been broken already in the 5.1 release, so you'd need the 5.0 release... Here's the [issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-2867), it *might* be solved for 5.2.0.M1 which will be released any day now, otherwise later.